# Counting the number div loaded from external php file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two php files, child.php and parent.php.  Child.php generates div.  Now, the parent.php calls child.php to be loaded in `<div id='divContainer'>`.  Now, I need to count the div inside the divContainer. Is it possible? 
I tried something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var total_record = $('#divContainer > div').length;
   alert(total_record);
});
```

But it's not working.  Even an empty alert is not popping out.
Can someone here, help me on this? THank you!

Comment: You have a syntax error on the last line, it should be `$(document).ready(function () {...});`

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: Are you loading the child using AJAX? You can't count it until after the AJAX call completes.

Comment: How can I check if the AJAX call is completed?

Comment: If your syntax is correct, then your code here should be working even if the content hasn't loaded yet, you'd get a count of 0.  Check your console for errors, put the `alert('hello world')` first thing in your ready function, and see if it fires.  Issue might be outside the code you show here.

Comment: I tried `alert('hello');` outside document.ready and it works. If I put it inside, it's not working. 

If I have this line of codes.. 


`<div id="black-contents" class="contents">
   <div id="divContainer" ></div>
   <div id="black" style="margin: auto;"></div>
</div>`



Is it the same if i wrote it like this: `$('#divContainer > div').length;` ??

Comment: I checked console and I got this.. 

`var i = $('#divContainer > div').length;`  -- ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Answer (score 5):

There's a syntax error:

```
)};
```

Should be:

```
});
```

Often if you are not getting any output/result at all when expected, it is down to a syntax error which will cause the browser to be unable to parse and execute the code. For future debugging, use the error console as this normally points out any errors with a decent description of the problem.

Comment: Also, jslint is your friend!